# Getting data from ajax Partial View to use in the parent View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to build a navigation system by which a user can navigate a category/sub-category structure and then allow the user to add new ones.

Here is my controller...

```
    public ActionResult ManageCategories()
    {
        var categoryService = new CategoryService(_unitOfWork);
        CategoryListViewModel model = categoryService.GetCategories(null);
        return View("ManageCategories", model);
    }


    public PartialViewResult GetCategories(int? parentCategoryId)
    {
        var categoryService = new CategoryService(_unitOfWork);
        CategoryListViewModel model = categoryService.GetCategories(parentCategoryId);

        return PartialView("GetCategories", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddNewCategory(string newCategoryName, int? parentCategoryId)
    {
        ...code to add new category to database...

        // just redirect for now...
        return RedirectToAction("ManageCategories", parentCategoryId);
    }
```

Here is my (simplified) view...

```
        @model CategoryListViewModel

        <ul id="category-explorer">
            @Html.Action("GetCategories", new { parentCategoryId = Model.ParentCategoryId })
        </ul>
```

Here is my partial view that just displays the list of subcategories for a given parent category...

```
@model CategoryListViewModel

@{

AjaxOptions ajaxOpts = new AjaxOptions 
{
    UpdateTargetId = "category-explorer",
};

}


@foreach(Category category in Model.Categories)
{    
    <li>@Ajax.ActionLink(@category.Name, "GetCategories", new {parentCategoryId = category.CategoryId}, ajaxOpts)</li>
}
```

A parentCategoryId of null means that category is a top level category. Inside my partial view I use ajax to again call the same partial view, but pass the selected category as the parentCategoryId, so it is a recursive stucture.

My issue is how does my ManageCategories view get the final value of parentCategoryId that the user nested down to? I have a form on my main view that needs to use this value so it can call 'AddCategory' appropriately.

I think the way I've set the ajax up and views is correct; just a bit stumped on how this can be achieved cleanly, i.e. without resorting to storing static variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was unaware that controllers are reconstructed between each HTTP request so any private values I was setting were being lost. The [TempData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.tempdata%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) class allowed me to save the last selected Id between requests inside the 'GetCategories' action.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by doing some manual JavaScript programming instead of falling back to the Ajax class in asp.net. By using jQuery (or other libraries, I just prefer jquery because its widely used and tends to get the job done most of the time) you can execute Ajax calls just as easily as by using asp.net ajax, and in addition store variables and stuff.

You could start by putting this in your partial view

```
@foreach(Category category in Model.Categories)
{    
    <li><a href="#" onclick="return loadCategory('@category.CategoryId');">@category.Name</a></li>
}
```

Clicking the link will now cause the browser to call the loadCategory JavaScript function, which you'll find below

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    var s_currentCategory = -1;
    var loadCategory = function(categoryId){

       $.get("/GetCategories?parentCategoryId=" + categoryId, // hard coded url
             function(data){ // Callback to handle the Ajax response
                 $("#category-explorer").html(data);
                 s_currentCategory = categoryId; 
             }

       return false; // to cancel the link click event, preventing the browser to follow the link

    }

</script>
```

At this point you have a reference to the categoryId that was last retrieved using Ajax. I'm not sure this is exactly what you wanted, but at least it should point you in the general direction.

I advice you to read up on the jquery api before using this code, because it does not provide a full, working example. For instance, you might want to add an error handler in case the Ajax call fails.

http://api.jquery.com/

Without seeing how you plan to hook up your AddCategory functionality, this is the best I can do. You say you want to avoid using a static variable, and my `s_currentCategory` might be concidered such. I'd be happy to try and give you some advice if you provide me with more details.

Comment: Thanks alot, I'll give it a try. In terms of 'AddCategory' I simply plan to have a form on the ManageCategories page that has inputs textbox (for the category name) and I need to bind the parentCategoryId the user selected to the form route values so when I submit it, both get passed as paramters to the 'AddCategory' method.

How could I access s_currentCategory in the ManageCategories view and use it in the form submission values?